# Java annotation processing - how to handle already processed code?

Tags: java, annotation-processing

If I have a class

```
@GenerateInterface
public class _FooImpl {}
```

I want to generate an interface

```
public interface Foo {}
```

that basically contains all the methods of `_FooImpl` (i.e. getters and setters).

Also if I have inheritance, like

```
@GenerateInterface
public class _ParentImpl {}

@GenerateInterface
public class _ChildImpl extends _ParentImpl {}
```

this should result in interface inheritance as well

```
public interface Parent {}

public interface Child extends Parent {}
```

I have a rough idea how to do that. But what if `_ParentImpl` is part of a library? That library also has to contain `Parent`.

In the annotation processor, how do I handle this? I can't generate the `Parent` interface again because then I'd have the same interface twice. Can I somehow detect that it already exists but distinguish it from files that do also already exist but are not part of the library and can thus be overriden?

I actually only need this for one class/interface that is extended by anything else. Thus I could remove `@GenerateInterface` from `_ParentImpl` and hardcode the inheritance of the `Parent` interface. This would be my last resort though. **Edit:** Or instead of removing the interface altogether, I could set `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)`, right?

Comment: An interface can't be extend a class. For inheritance among interfaces, you have to use implements. For ex: Interface_Child implements Interface_Parent

Comment: @DheerajRoy no that is not true. Interfaces can `extend` each other...

Comment: Yes Interface can extend each other, but interface cant extend a class

Comment: @DheerajRoy that's true. I do, however, not try to do that anywhere O.o

Comment: Your issue is not clear. Can you simplify what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I just want to generate a java file based on an annotation. Now, if an annotated type (and therefore the generated one as well) is part of a library, what do I do? The annotated type (if `RetentionPolicy` is not `SOURCE`) will be processed by the annotation processor again but the generated file already exists. How do I handle that?

Comment: Can you show code which you have been working on?

Comment: I have no code for the processor yet because I wanted to understand the concept first. The actual code generation is irrelevant to this issue anyways. I'm currently setting up a complete project to simulate this and maybe find a solution myself...

Comment: @DheerajRoy Okay, I think I found the solution myself. See answer below. Thank you for your effort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Already compiled classes are not processed again.**

I created a complete test set-up and explored the issue myself. Turns out, only files that actually have to be compiled are run through annotation processing. This means I can safely include `_ParentImpl` and `Parent` in the library. `_ParentImpl` can keep the annotation, it is then possible to use `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)` in connection with `@Inherited` to apply the annotation to subclasses in a very convenient manner.